# Proving $\frac{a}{a^2+1}+\frac{b}{b^2+1} ≤ \frac{1}{2}$

Tags: inequality

How to prove that :

$$\frac{a}{a^2+1}+\frac{b}{b^2+1} ≤ \frac{1}{2}$$

$a,b$ are real positive numbers

Comment: You you try to format your LaTeX more properly? Does $a2$ mean $a^2$? Also, what types of numbers are $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Does $a2$ mean $a^2$, $a\cdot2$, or $a_2$? No matter, in each of those cases setting all variables equal to $1$ shows your inequality is not true.

Comment: @alex.jordan Unless he/she wants to prove it for $a,b\neq1$.

Comment: @Dima OK, what about 1.00001?

Comment: @DimaMcGreen You can take $a,b$ arbitrarily close to $1$ and the inequality will still be violated. In fact for any positive $b$, we can choose $a$ such that the inequality is violated.

Comment: Counter example a=b=1.

Comment: @alex.jordan Sure, but I was just saying that without knowing what $a$ and $b$ are, there can't be a right or wrong answer.

Comment: This inequality is not always true.And there are many counter examples  , the most trivial one's are $a=b=1$. And every it's not true for every real numbers in the interval $[1,3]$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your inequality is incorrect. For instance, $a=b=1$, gives us the left hand side to be equal to $1$, which is clearly greater than $\dfrac12$. The inquality should possibly read $$\dfrac{a}{a^2+1} + \dfrac{b}{b^2+1} \leq 1$$

---

We have from AM-GM$$a+ \dfrac1a \geq 2 \,\, \text{ and } b + \dfrac1b \geq 2$$
Hence, we get that
$$\dfrac{a^2+1}a \geq 2 \,\, \text{ and } \dfrac{b^2+1}b \geq 2$$
This gives us
$$\dfrac{a}{a^2+1} \leq \dfrac12 \,\, \text{ and } \dfrac{b}{b^2+1} \leq \dfrac 12$$
Adding both gives us
$$\dfrac{a}{a^2+1} + \dfrac{b}{b^2+1} \leq 1$$

Answer (score 2):

$(a-1)^2 \ge 0$

$a^2 +1 -2a\ge 0$

$a^2+1 \ge 2a$

When you invert the the expression, the inequality also changes.

$\dfrac{1}{a^2+1} \le \dfrac{1}{2a}$

Similarly, $\dfrac{1}{b^2+1} \le \dfrac{1}{2b}$

Now,

$$\dfrac{1a}{a^2+1} \le \dfrac{1}{2}$$

$$\dfrac{1a}{a^2+1} \le \dfrac{1}{2}$$

Add them both, you have

$$\dfrac{1a}{a^2+1} + \dfrac{1b}{b^2+1} \le 1$$

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite as $\frac{1}{a+\frac{1}{a}}+\frac{1}{b+\frac{1}{b}}$.  For positive $a$, $a+\frac{1}{a} \ge 2$.  Therefore you can claim that LHS $\le 1$.  For negative $a$ it's trivially true.